# How do I split a WordPress theme into 2 columns?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to split my WordPress theme (I'm working from [The Buffet Framework](http://www.zy.sg/the-buffet-framework/)) into 2 columns, like a magazine or newspaper. The term "2-column" usually refers to a sidebar, but I want to get 2 columns of posts in addition to the right sidebar. I'm assuming this is just a simple matter of some basic HTML or CSS column creating, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about multi-column layout in CSS3 which is not widely supported yet:

http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

If you want wider support, try jQuery to do this:

http://welcome.totheinter.net/2008/07/22/multi-column-layout-with-css-and-jquery/

note: it crashes occassionally (especially with images)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen quite a few WordPress themes that do multiple columns, I guess they're using PHP. I'll give that JQuery link a try, it looks like it should work.